# Verifying my proof that if $|S(x)| \leq 1$, then $\lim_{x \to 0} x\cdot S(1/x) = 0$

Tags: analysis, limits, proof-verification

Question:

> Suppose that $S : R \to R$ is a function so that for all $x$, $−1 \leq S(x) \leq 1$.
>
> Prove from the limit definition that
>
> $$\lim_{x\to0} x \cdot S(1/x) = 0.$$

This is my proof:

> Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Let $\delta = \epsilon \cdot S^{-1}(1/x)$.
>
> So if $0<x<\delta$ then $$|\,x\,|<\epsilon \cdot S^{-1}(1/x)\to \left|\,x \cdot S(1/x)-0\,\right|<e = \left|\,x \cdot S(1/x)-0\,\right|<\epsilon$$
>
> Therefore we have shown that $\lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot S(1/x) = 0$.

Comment: $\delta$ cannot depend on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of $S$, $$|xS(\frac1x)-0|\le |x-0|.$$
If $x$ tends to $0$, so does $xS(\frac1x)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Prove that if $\text{lim}\  x_n = 0$ and $\lbrace y_n \rbrace$ is a limited sequence then $\text{lim}\  (x_n\dot\ y_n) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your $\delta$ must be independant on $x$.

**Hint:**

Let us put $f(x)=xS(\frac 1x)$

Since $S(t) \leq 1$  for all $t \in \mathbb R$ we have:

$$\forall x\in {\mathbb R} \backslash \{0\} \quad |f(x)| \leq |x| $$

let $\varepsilon > 0$, if  $\delta =\varepsilon$ then:

$$\forall x\in {\mathbb R}\backslash \{0\}  \quad |x| < \delta  \Rightarrow |f(x)| \leq |x| < \varepsilon$$

That means:

$$\forall x\in {\mathbb R}\backslash \{0\}  \quad |x-0| < \delta  \Rightarrow |f(x)-0| \leq |x| < \varepsilon$$

Comment: So then would I subtract a zero from both $f(x)$ and $x$ because wouldn't that be the limit definition. Then it would be proven?

Comment: Yes. It was an indication. I just added this by editing.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof as stated doesn't work, as your delta depends on $x$. You can do this proof without using epsilon-delta (unless the problem specifically requires you to do so). This could instead be a nice application of the squeeze theorem. We have $$-1 \leq S\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \leq 1 \\ \implies -x \leq x\cdot S\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \leq x$$ It should be clear what happens if you take the limit as $x \to 0$.